# Ionic Framework : How to Upgrade to Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I use ionic stable version to build Hybrid Mobile Application and things going fine.

Now, I would like to use Ionic 2 for its components features. Hence, I have installed ionic on ubuntu as

```
$ npm install -g ionic@beta
```

And then start using ionic started template as

```
$ ionic start IonicMyV2 --v2
```

However, the above command always brings the stable version ionic template.

What I am doing wrong? What procedure do I have to follow to use Ionic 2?

Comment: What do you mean by 'stable version ionic template' ?

Comment: The version, I installed by $ npm install -g ionic. My Exact problem is when I command $ ionic start IonicMyV2 --v2, it always bring ionic old version.

Answer (score 1):

My problem has been resolved by command

sudo npm install -g ionic@beta  cordova

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the need for `sudo` with npm by installing NodeJS via brew:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

brew install node

node -v
npm -v

npm install -g ionic@beta
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run below command for upgrade to ionic 2.

> npm install -g cordova ionic